Language Resource is not working in .NET Core API
Code in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("zh-CN")
            };

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportedCultures.FirstOrDefault());
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

var localizationOptions = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>()?.Value;
localizationOptions.FallBackToParentCultures = true;
localizationOptions.FallBackToParentUICultures = true;
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

Folder structure:\

MyProject (API)
├── Controllers
│   ├── TestController.cs
│
├── Resources
│   ├── Shared
│    --├── SharedResource.cs
│    --├── SharedResources.en-US.resx
│    --└── SharedResources.zh-CN.resx

Code in API controller:
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<ResourcesController> _localizer;

    public TestController(IStringLocalizer<ResourcesController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    [HttpGet("TestCulture")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestCulture()
    {
        var testMsg = _localizer["NotFound"].Value;

        return Ok(testMsg);
    }
}

I basically tried the tutorial and even chatGPT to the letter, but it doesn't work. Any tips on how I can tackle this? Much appreciated!

Never follow ChatGPT to the letter - it can "guide" at most. And - what is the exact problem you are having? If "nothing works", then start over.

i tried from many online sources, including in Stack. well, im using JSON now, and it work. though its nice to know whats wrong.

It is a project structure issue. After my test , please follow this structure. Meanwhile , please check your file name to be correct.
MyProject (API)
├── Controllers
│ ├── TestController.cs
│
├── Resources
│ ├── SharedResources.en-US.resx
│ ├── SharedResources.zh-CN.resx
├── SharedResources.cs




thanks! it is the structure. much appreciated!
